# Using http-basic-authentication with spring webservices

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-ws, basic-authentication

I followed https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/ to implement simple webservice using Spring. Everything works like expected. Now I am trying to add http basic authentication to it using javaconfig. How should I proceed? I found some links where @EnableWebSecurity was used however nothing seems to work... Service responds without authentication...

Answer (score 3):

Just create a Spring Security config file like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("ROLE_USER");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .formLogin()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
    }
```

Here's a notice tutorial to follow up: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately this doesn't help. Service responds without authentication...

Comment: We will need some code and project structure to help you at this point.

Comment: I am doing some basic mistake... Only working solution for me now is to add custom authenticationEntryPoint to httpBasic() which closes outputstream of response which causes java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed... Anythig other, even response.sendError(SC_UNAUTHORIZED) in authenticationEntryPoint leads to execute request sucessfully... So it means application "knows" that user is not authenticated (as it calls authenticationentrypoint) but it just ignores it...

Comment: thanks @Lukehey, some of the tutorials are a bit bloated and this simplified it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the tags you added to the question I see you are exposing the SOAP service using Spring Boot. In that case just add the `spring-boot-starter-security` [Spring Boot starter project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-starters) as a dependency. This will include Spring Security and [by default ‘basic’ authentication is added on all HTTP endpoints](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security) (including your SOAP service).

By default a random password is generated at startup but you can configure your own user name/password using [Spring Boot security properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

If would like more information, I created a blog post which illustrates [how to setup Spring WS basic authentication using Spring Boot](https://www.codenotfound.com/2017/04/spring-ws-basic-authentication-example.html).